# Can debug logging be added to firestore rules functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Given that the firestore rules structure allows for functions, is there some way to add debug logs to those **rule-functions** ? .. in order to verify that the function you expect, is in fact being called.

I see that with the simulator it shows a red X at the line in the rules sturcture, where access is denied for a given simulation-request.  However, am curious for verification in production mode so it can be communicated to parties concerned about the *rules integrity*.

In the example below, I was thinking it might be implemented with that commented-out line:

`console.log('ENTER: isAccessOn()');`

However this does not work.  Asking here in case there's any option for something like this in the platform.. or if not, if there's a suggestion for how to make such verifications with a production deployment. Thanks

```js
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // block client access
    function isAccessOn() {
      // console.log('ENTER: isAccessOn()');
      return false;
    }

    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if isAccessOn();
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firestore rules now have a
[debug() function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.debug)

It's still not brilliant but better than before.

Comment: This does not work in production, only on the Firebase emulator.  According to the linked docs: "debug function blocks are only executed by the Security Rules engine in the Firestore emulator, part of the Firebase Emulator Suite. The debug function has no effect in production."

Comment: @DougStevenson, ouch & interesting.  In OP, the title is general but in OP body I do mention *"production"* for getting the debug output.  So now, not sure which answer to accept, because this is in fact useful to provide logging we can get back from the runtime execution even if just at the emulator level.

Comment: Well, you would typically accept the one that is *most* useful, but upvote all of them that are at least somewhat helpful.

Comment: This is definitely something more available to us than we had before for this kind of debug work/verification, so I will leave the Accept on this one.  Standing by for the next iteration :).  Thanks Doug

Comment: I'd argue that you shouldn't use your production app for debugging ;-)
Whatever next, a way to console.log? We'd be so spoiled.

Comment: Is there a similar tool for Firebase Realtime Database?

Comment: @Stefan "production" in firebase language is just "not in emulator". This could still be the dev environment.

Answer (score 14):

You may want to look into [local rules emulation using the Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/test-rules-emulator), which is a brand new feature of the CLI.  You can do simple logging with the emulator with the [debug()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.debug) function.

However, there is no way to log anything in security rules in production.  If you want to verify that your rules work as expected, you should write some integration tests for those and run your tests to make sure access is rejected or allowed according to your specifications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the debug function in rules like this:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /{document=**} {
    // show paths being requested
    allow create, read, update, delete: if debug(request.path);
  }
}
```

Then watch the log file:

```
tail -f firestore-debug.log
```